# Mysql subquery order when using IN

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by

Does the order of the results inside a mysql subquery affect the order of the actual query?
I tried it but did not came to a real result cause sometimes it seemed so and sometimes it doesn't.

eg:

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE pid IN (SELECT mid FROM member ORDER BY mdate)
```

Is the "order by"-clause going to affect the order of the results in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Does "it can't" mean that there is absolutely no way to do this?

Comment: What to do? To affect on result order using order by clause in subquery? My answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it cant and if you want to change the order as per your need then better use a `JOIN`

Something like this:-

```
select name 
from people p inner join member m on p.pid = m.mid
order by p.name
```

Comment: **wont work here** means that this is only a small part of my query and that it is causing problems in other places but you already answered my question here :D

Comment: I am sorry but I didnt get you very clearly. Does my answer answers your query???

Comment: It does answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your outer query doesn't have `ORDER BY`; thus, order is not guaranteed.

I guess the only part which may be affected in this particular case is optimizer which might generate a different execution plan depends on how results of subquery are sorted...

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of whether or not the outer query results depend on the order by clause in the sub-query, one should never depend on the order. If you need any particular order of outer query results, you should explicitly use  order by clause on the outer query. AFAK, it makes sense to use order by clause in a sub-query only if you have to use TOP clause in SELECT clause of the sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

It really can't.  The data is coming from the `from` clause.  Your subquery is in the `where` clause.  It is just used to filter the rows.  If you want the ordering:

```
select p.name
from people p join
     (select member, min(mdate) as minmdate
      from member
      group by member
     ) m
     on p.pid = m.mid
order by minmdate;
```

That is, join in the results between the two tables.  I am assuming that `member` could have duplicates, and you want the earliest date associated with each member.